# Scrolling doesn't rotate around the model anymore, just zooms in and out

Tags: 3d-view

I'm not sure what I did, but scrolling no longer lets me "look around" my object, it just scrolls in and out of it.

Edit: So this morning, I open up the program, and it's working again. I didn't change any settings between using the 3-button mouse settings like Chebhou said. Not sure what happened. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Could clarify exactly what is happening? Are you using MMB?

Comment: You can open file menu and load factory settings.

Comment: I don't know what MMB is.

Comment: I did load factory settings, but it's still doing it.

Comment: Middle Mouse Button, pushing down on the scroll wheel

Comment: Oh, my bad, not used to seeing the letters by itself. I don't have a MMB, I have a trackpad.

Comment: Are you using the same method though?

Comment: enable Emulate 3 button Mouse and use  LMB+ Alt to rotate the view

Comment: @Shawn If that worked let Chebhou know so he can post an answer

Comment: Just to get this clear, but scrolling never used to rotate the viewport unless you set it that way, scrolling always zooms in and out by default.

Comment: @VinceScalia Weird, I do not remember that. Maybe there was a setting the tutorial told me to use for touchpads? Thanks!

Comment: veery interesting. @Chebhou, you can go ahead and answer. toodles

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise It happened again today, and yeah, I am using the same method. In the middle of the program, scrolling with two fingers on my trackpad just zooms in and out rather than rotate around where I am centered.

Comment: Interesting. Using a trackpad could get very different results from using a mouse. Also, using Emulate 3-Button Mouse uses Ctrl+LMB, no need for the trackpad at all.

Comment: I never used a mouse to begin with, and I never had to use the 3-Button Mouse setting to rotate, nor use Ctrl+LMB, it would just rotate around the center by scrolling on the trackpad.